# How to get child's element state from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child

I have a **SortSelect**(child) component that I want to put in my **Home**(parent) component.

```
export default function SortSelect() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [sortType, setSortType] = useState('asc');
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setSortType(event.target.value);
    };

    return (
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                <Select
                    value={sortType}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    displayEmpty
                    className={classes.selectEmpty}
                    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Without label' }}
                >
                    <MenuItem value='asc'>Count asc</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value='desc'>Count desc</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value='a-z'>Name A-Z</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value='z-a'>Name Z-A</MenuItem>
                </Select>
                <FormHelperText>Sort by</FormHelperText>
            </FormControl>
    );
}
```

I need to get **SortSelect's** *sortType* state, so I can sort my array. How can I do this?

Comment: You do the same as the `Select` element: You accept a callback as prop and call it whenever the value changes.

Comment: Is having your `Home` component create that `SortSelect` using `<SortSelect ... sortType={this.state.sortType} onSortChange={sortType => this.setState({ sortType })}>`, where you just call `this.props.onSortChange()` as part of your sort select component switching types not an option? Because React parents should _not_ need to know anything about their child states. Either they dictate the data by passing props (potentially managed through their _own_ state), or that data is local to the child and the child is responsible for whatever UI it's used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really doesn't sound like a pattern that you should implement with React. If the parent component needs that state, then it should handle it and pass the state as a prop to `SortSelect`.

If it needs the `sortType` only momentarily instead of having it in its state, then you could simply pass a callback from `Home` to `SortSelect` that's called in `SortSelect`'s `handleChange` function.

Just as a note, it is possible to expose state to a parent component using React's [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook, but you really shouldn't use that unless you are 100% sure of what you're doing.